# mysql unique two column error

Tags: mysql, unique-key

I am experiencing an error in creating a unique key constraint in MySQL. I have a unique key constraint in MySQL. I have a table with two columns of type VARCHAR() and I need to create a unique key constraint with these two columns, however when I am creating a duplicate record error occurs. I'm sure that is not duplicate record, because these two columns represent a content listing of a directory in Windows, which by default does not accept filenames equal in the same folder.

Create statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `filelist`.`fileserver`;
CREATE TABLE  `filelist`.`fileserver` (
  `nome` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `caminho` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `dataCriacao` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `dataUltimoAcesso` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `dataUltimaModificacao` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `tamanho` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Command to create a unique key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE filelist.fileserver ADD UNIQUE(`caminho`, `nome`);
```

Error message:

Duplicate entry 'F:\Fileserver\OM\OM_ADMINISTRATIVO\VIAGEM\Autorizações\2014\10' for key 'caminho'

Table content:

```
SELECT * FROM filelist.fileserver WHERE caminho LIKE 'F:\\\\Fileserver\\\\OM\\\\OM_ADMINISTRATIVO\\\\VIAGEM\\\\Autorizações\\\\2014\\\\10%' ORDER BY nome;

nome
Alex - 02 a 03 de outubro.pdf
Alex - 28 a 31 de outubro.pdf
Antonio e Donizete - 17 de outubro.pdf
Arianny - 27 a 28 de outubro.pdf
Denison - 07 a 10 de outubro.pdf
Denison - 29 a 31 de outubro.pdf
Edeildo - 14 a 17 de outubro.pdf
Edeildo - 27 a 31 de outubro.pdf
Edeildo - 29 de setembro a 01 de outubro.pdf
Guilherme - 14 de outubro.pdf
Guilherme - 16 de outubro.pdf
Guilherme - 21 a 23 de outubro.pdf
Guilherme - 27 de outubro.pdf
Jan - 30 de setembro a 10 de outubro.pdf
Jan - 30 de setembro a 24 de outubro.pdf
Jose Eduardo - 12 a 17 de outubro.pdf
José Eduardo - 12 a 17 de outubro.pdf
Lucette - 29 de outubro a 07 de novembro.pdf
Lucette - 30 de setembro a 2 de outubro.pdf
Luis - 06 a 07 de outubro.pdf
Luis Claudio - 09 a 10 de outubro.pdf
Luis Claudio - 30 a 31 de outubro.pdf
Mariana - 01 a 03 de outubro.pdf
Mateus - 16 a 19 de outubro.pdf
Mauricio - 13 a 17 de outubro.pdf
Paulo - 14 a 17 de outubro.pdf
Paulo - 27 a 31 de outubro.pdf
Paulo - 29 de setembro a 01 de outubro.pdf
Rogério - 09 a 10 de outubro.pdf
Ronaldo - 02 a 03 de outubro.pdf
Ronaldo - 06 a 07 de outubro.pdf
Ronaldo - 16 de outubro.pdf
Ronaldo - 21 de outubro.pdf
Ronaldo - 27 a 28 de outubro.pdf
Ronaldo - Locação de Veículo.pdf
Silvana - 05 a 10 de outubro.pdf
Silvana - 05 a 24 de outubro.pdf
Tiago - 07 a 10 de outubro.pdf
```

[]s

Comment: If you want to DELETE the exisintg duplicates you can do `ALTER IGNORE TABLE filelist.fileserver ADD UNIQUE(`caminho`, `nome`);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem come from these 2 rows:

```
Jose Eduardo - 12 a 17 de outubro.pdf
José Eduardo - 12 a 17 de outubro.pdf
```

Surely a collation problem, try these 2 commands and you will see the difference:

```
SELECT 'é' = 'e' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
SELECT 'é' = 'e' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

The first match, the second not.

A solution is to change your table default collation.
You can also change the collation by column but I don't know which value the constraint will use...

Comment: Hi FLefèvre, I change the collation to utf8_bin and run again the command to create the constraint. Same error. Do you know if it is necessary to re-insert all the data in the table, because the change of the collation?

Comment: Try to convert table: check `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Confirmed: `ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin` resolve the problem

Comment: Hi FLefèvre, did work!!! I converted the table char set, and then apply the unique key. Some error occurs, because the unique key validation, but I correct the data and voialà!!! Thanks for your help... and tips

Answer (score 0):

Somehwere in your databese the value for caminho: 'F:\Fileserver\OM\OM_ADMINISTRATIVO\VIAGEM\Autorizações\2014\10' is already saved, do your "`select * from ..`" without the `\\\\` and you should find it.

You can also try a query:

```
Select * from * FROM filelist.fileserver WHERE caminho LIKE '%Autorizações%'
```

`%` Means there can be more characters before or after, this will return all results that contain 'Autorizações'.

Try finding similar results, I hope it helps